# I want create a huge matrix with scipy, 70,000 rows, 70,000 columns

Tags: scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to use Python's SciPy to create a huge matrix, 70,000 rows, 70,000 columns. Which sparse matrix in SciPy would work?

Comment: the sparse.eye(70000) and dia_matrix does not work, both of them raise "Memory Error"

Comment: Unless you are using a 12 year old version of scipy then there is something you are not telling us, or you have absolutely no free memory. Using scipy 1.6.2, a 70000 x 70000  csr format identity matrix uses about 1Mb of total storage

Comment: oh, ”absolutely no free memory”.e  you mean i need change the windows memory setting? my scipy version is 1.4.1

Comment: No I mean that unless you have some sort of system problem you haven't told us about, or you are doing this in a Python shell which has been running for weeks without garbage collection, then this should work. A diagonal format double precision sparse array of the size you mentioned should take 500kb of ram. I think my cat has that much free ram, and he is 10 years old, and isn't rebooted very often

Comment: csr_matrix works! haha :) , thank you very much!!! I am so stupid!